# Preradicals commute with coproducts

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'd like to prove the following statement (Exercise 2(i) from Stenstrom, Rings of Quotients, page 157):

*Let $\cal C$ be a small abelian category. Then any preradical $r\colon {\cal C}\to{\cal C}$ preserves coproducts.*

One has to show that given a fixed object $A\in{\cal C}$, for any family of subobjects $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of $A$ with embeddings $\varepsilon_i\colon A_i\to \bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i$, then the natural morphism
$$
  \varrho\colon \bigoplus_{i\in I}r(A_i)\longrightarrow r(\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i)
$$
induced by the family $(r(\varepsilon_i))_{i\in I}$, is an isomorphism.

Now, my idea is to exploit the facts that the preradical $r$ preserves monomorphisms and that, by definition of union of a family of subobjects, namely $\mathop{\rm Im}\varrho=\sum_{i\in I}r(A_i)$, we would have that
$$
\bigoplus_{i\in I}r(A_i)=\sum_{i\in I}r(A_i),
$$
which would imply that $\varrho$ is a monomorphism, and then that
$$
r(\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i)=\sum_{i\in I}r(A_i)
$$
as well. However, I am not able to prove my claims. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the definition of "preradical" in the book?  For at least one definition of preradical that I've seen, I don't think this statement is true.

Comment: @EricWofsey In Stentrom's book, preradical stands for a subfunctor of the identity functor of $\cal C$, i.e. a functor that assigns to each $A\in{\cal C}$ a subobject $r(A)$ and consequently a functor preserving monomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  For instance, let $\mathcal{C}$ be the opposite category of abelian groups (say, of cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ to make it essentially small).  There is a preradical $r$ on $\mathcal{C}$ which sends each abelian group $A$ to the quotient $A/T(A)$ by the torsion subgroup of $A$.  This $r$ does not preserve coproducts (i.e., products of abelian groups); for instance, $r(\mathbb{Z}/(2^n))=0$ for each $n$ but $r(\prod_n\mathbb{Z}/(2^n))$ is nontrivial (for instance, the element of $\prod_n\mathbb{Z}/(2^n)$ which is $1$ on every coordinate is not torsion).

Comment: So, that exercise... cannot be proven at all?! Are there conditions on $\cal C$ or on the preradical $r$ making it solvable?

Comment: Assuming that the relevant products and coproducts exist, it seems that what you need is that the preimage of $\prod r(A_i)$ under the natural map $\bigoplus A_i\to \prod A_i$ is $\bigoplus r(A_i)$.  This is true in most "natural" examples (for instance, categories of modules).

Comment: In particular, if I'm not mistaken, this will hold in any abelian category satisfying axioms AB5 and AB3*, and in particular in any Grothendieck category.  (Here for convenience I am requiring all products and coproducts exist, which is incompatible with smallness; if you want $\mathcal{C}$ to be small you can make analogous assumptions that only apply to the particular products and coproducts you need to exist.)

Comment: Yes, it's true: the statement should hold at least in module categories (in view of Stentrom's setting). Anyway, do you have any hint in the case of $\cal C$ Grothendieck in order to prove my above claims?

Comment: The point is that by considering functoriality of $r$ with respect to the inclusion maps $A_i\to \bigoplus A_i$ and the projection maps $\bigoplus A_i\to A_i$, $r(\bigoplus A_i)$ must be a subobject of $\bigoplus A_i$ that contains $\bigoplus r(A_i)$ and whose projection onto $A_i$ is contained in $r(A_i)$ for each $i$.  This latter condition says exactly that $r(\bigoplus A_i)$ is contained in the preimage of $\prod r(A_i)$ under the natural map $\bigoplus A_i\to \prod A_i$.  If that preimage is $\bigoplus r(A_i)$, we're done.

Comment: To prove the preimage is $\bigoplus r(A_i)$ in a Grothendieck category, note that AB5 implies the natural map $(\bigoplus A_i)/(\bigoplus r(A_i))\cong \bigoplus A_i/r(A_i)\to \prod A_i/r(A_i)$ is monic.  But we can factor this map as a composition $(\bigoplus A_i)/(\bigoplus r(A_i))\to (\prod A_i)/(\prod r(A_i))\to \prod A_i/r(A_i)$ and so the first map $(\bigoplus A_i)/(\bigoplus r(A_i))\to (\prod A_i)/(\prod r(A_i))$ must be monic.  This tells us exactly that the preimage of $\prod r(A_i)$ in $\bigoplus A_i$ is $\bigoplus r(A_i)$.